# Can you access Lacie 2Big visible to two macs via daisy chain?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, daisychaining, lacie, thunderbolt-networking

Hi I'm planning to connect lacie to mac A and mac B via thunderbolt 3 daisy chain.

It is visible on the directly connected mac but not on the other one.

Is there a way I can access it from the mac B without doing file sharing from mac A?

Answer (score 2):

Use file sharing.

Having one drive mounted simultaneously to two computers [even if they would let you do that] would be a disaster just waiting to happen.

What if one machine updated a file the other had open? Which is in charge? Which decides which version of any file is the "correct" one?

Networks sharing is capable of handling those conflicts.